VSCode Devcontainer terminal unable to git fetch
While in my VSCode Devcontainer, attempting to run a fetch command results in
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Initially I had this issue and was able to resolve it following this answer but now it has reoccurred. What am I missing to get access rights?
I've run ssh-add -l in the vscode terminal and I see the key showing and confirmed that ssh-agent is running.

Welcome to Stack overflow! Please provide the command you used in order to help us in aiding you!

Try ssh -T git@github.com to test the SSH connection.

My guess is that you didn't set up your github ssh access keys correctly. see here

Running ssh -T git@github.com results in git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

I believe the key is set correctly, I can run a successful git fetch from the Ubuntu terminal in WSL2, the issue is only when running in the VSCode terminal.
